# Cors policy error when using Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, angular8, asp.net-core-3.0, authorize-attribute

I am getting a cors policy error whenever I use Authorize attribute on my user controller.I am using Angular 8 as my front-end framework and asp .net core 3.0.0 as my backend.It is working fine if I remove the authorize attribute from the controller.
[image: Console error].
Below is my **startup.cs** file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using DatingApp.API.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace DatingApp.API {
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(DatingRepository).Assembly);
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IDatingRepository, DatingRepository>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
                {
                    builder.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (error != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                        }
                    });
                });
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                // app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("CorsPolicy");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

This is my **usercontroller**
[image]

Comment: Why are you using the Authorization filter in the first place. I cant find where you have configured you authorization in your services, despite you adding it to the middleware

Comment: CORS is not about authorization. Please take a look at [authorization in ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Getting same error even after I place the authorize attribute to last.

Comment: I don't see any configuration for the authorization in the above link.

Comment: Can you move app.UseCors(“CorsPolicy”) code above app.UseAuthorization()? The order in which middleware is added matters!

Comment: @Bob it gives me some different error now.

Comment: @FIRE after this change, what is your latest error message?

Comment: @Bob I managed to fix it. btw The error was related to adding the AuthenticationSchema . Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` for adding the authentication as a middleware in my startup.cs file and then I also need to configure the same in my services.
Here is modification in **startup.cs** file
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If anyone faces a similar issue and has their Authentication already setup correctly in `startup.cs` file.
Remember folks below is the right hierarchy:

```
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

*I was using `app.UseCors()` below authentication which was causing the issue.*